# Finding floor & ceiling in BST with Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, binary-search-tree, floor

I've been given the following piece of code and I'm expected to complete it. The purpose is to design a function which will calculate the floor of a given element k in a BST. The floor of an element 'k' in a BST is the greatest key that is smaller than 'k'.

I'm really at a loss... I've already programmed this for Java, but haven't been able to work it out in Haskell.

```
floor :: Ord a => a -> ABST a -> Maybe a
floor x Empty    = Nothing
floor x (Node y w lt rt) 
  | x == y       = Just y
  | x < y = undefined
  | x > y = undefined
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: First find the largest subtree all of whose elements are smaller than k (ie, traverse the tree until you find a node which is smaller than k). Then return the greatest element of that tree. It is probably easiest to write this as two different functions.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to check whether the "natural" recursive calls help in solving this problem.

That is, consider:

```
floor :: Ord a => a -> ABST a -> Maybe a
floor x Empty    = Nothing
floor x (Node y w lt rt) 
  | x == y       = Just y
  | x < y = ???
  | x > y = ???
  where floorL = floor x lt
        floorR = floor x rt
```

Then, is there some way to exploit `floorL,floorR` to achieve the wanted result?